# Анимированная синусоида с фиксированными начальной и конечной точками

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

У меня есть синусоидальная волна на холсте, которая качается влево и вправо. Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы начальная и конечная точки оставались зафиксированными. Как это сделать?

```js
function start() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCurves(context, step);

  step += 5;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
}

var step = -4;

function drawCurves(ctx, step) {
  var width = ctx.canvas.width;
  var height = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 4;
  var y = 0;
  var amplitude = 20;
  var frequency = 90;
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math.sin((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="start()">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="2000"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animate sine wave, fixed start and end points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56082963/7394871) от участника  [@kontenurban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10542593/kontenurban).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56082963/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLSL вариация на тему, добиться желаемого эффекта просто за счет того что система координат в этом шейдере от 0 до 1, соответственно частота должна быть кратна `пи`

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(`attribute vec2 v;void main(void){gl_Position=vec4(v.xy,0.,1.);}`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader(document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl"]`).textContent, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);
let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);
let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(time, t/500)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="600" id="canvas"/>
<script type="glsl">
precision highp float;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
  vec2 p = 20.*uv - 10.;
  vec3 f = vec3(0.);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+5.*sin(time*2.)*sin(uv.y*3.1415*4.)+cos(uv.y*11.)),-0.8)*vec3(.5,.0,.5);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+4.*sin(time*3.)*sin(uv.y*3.1415*1.)+cos(uv.y*21.)),-0.8)*vec3(.5,.5,.0);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+3.*sin(time*5.)*sin(uv.y*3.1415*2.)+cos(uv.y*17.)),-0.8)*vec3(.0,.5,.5);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(f, 1.);  
}
</script>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/xNBayG

Comment: Я догадывался, что ты не пройдёшь мимо этого топика. Можно сказать, специально для тебя перевёл :=)  Замечательно, классно получилось. Сделай ещё один штрих,- вертикально поверни синусоиду, как у автора вопроса, чтобы создавалось впечатление вращения. (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вчера я почему-то его не увидел, наверное был сильно занят рыбьим глазом =)

Comment: видимо, для достижения эффекта вращения нужно было сделать одинаковую амплитуду синусоид и время. Ладно, не буду придираться, - галочка твоя :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT если сделать один цвет то ощущение вращения чуть посильнее

Comment: а ты всё-таки попробуй поиграться с амплтудой и временем. А насчет цвета, есть такой лоадер Барби, может видел - цилиндр с цветными винтообразными полосками

Comment: @Alexandr_TT можно сразу в 3д нарисовать:) только там математика позабористее :)

Comment: тебе видней, Константин

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не охото портить пример, он сейчас очень простой для исследования :)

Answer (score 3):

Я изменил размер вашего холста, потому что хотел увидеть его весь. Вы можете изменить его размер обратно на то, что вам нужно.

Я сделал 2 вещи:

1. Частота должна быть переменной `frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);` или `frequency = height / (4 * Math.PI) ;`. Делитель должен быть кратным - `2 * Math.PI`
2. Я перенаправляю контекст в противоположном направлении с теми же значениями: `ctx.translate (-amplitude * Math.sin (step / frequency), 0);`

Если вам нужно более тонкое  регулирование колебания, играйте с амплитудой.

В моем коде есть закомментированная `ctx.closePath()`. Пожалуйста, раскомментируйте эту строку, чтобы ясно увидеть, что синусоида остается фиксированной в центре. Я надеюсь, что это то, что вы спрашивали.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


function start() {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCurves(context, step);

  step += 5;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
}

var step = -4;

function drawCurves(ctx, step) {
  var width = ctx.canvas.width;
  var height = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var amplitude = 10;
  var frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-amplitude * Math.sin(step / frequency), 0);
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math.sin((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }
  //ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

start();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

В том случае, если вам нужно использовать несколько кривых, вы можете сделать это так:

Я помещаю все функции для рисования волны в функцию `drawWwing`, которая принимает в качестве аргументов амплитуду и тригонометрическую функцию (sin или cos):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = ctx.canvas.width;
var height = ctx.canvas.height;
var step = -4;

function start() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  drawWave(10,"sin");
  drawWave(10,"cos");
  drawWave(5,"sin");
  
  step += 5; 
}


  
function drawWave(amplitude,trig){
  // trig is the trigonometric function to be used: sin or cos
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  //var amplitude = 10;
  var frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-amplitude * Math[trig](step / frequency), 0);
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math[trig]((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

start();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56102865/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>